# Using the spherical law of cosines

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-geometry

Compute angular length $c$ of the great-circle route between these two cities:

- Daytona Beach (location A): $29^\circ12'\ N, 81^\circ1' \ W$.
- Sidi Ifni (location B): $29^\circ23' \ N. 10^\circ10' \ W$.

Ok so I converted the latitudes and longitudes and I now have:

- Daytona Beach (location A): $29.20^\circ N, 81.02^\circ W$
- Sidi Ifni (location B): $29.38^\circ N, 10.16^\circ W$

  $$\cos N = .18º$$

After using the law of cosines:

$$\cos c = \cos(81.02^\circ)\cos(10.16^\circ) + \sin(81.02^\circ)\sin(10.16^\circ)\cos(.18^\circ) = 0.3279$$
$$\arccos(0.3279) = 70.86^\circ = c$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: In your work, I think you have the values for latitude (north/south) and longitude (east/west) swapped.  I'd expect $\cos n=$ $$\cos(90°-29.20°)\cos(90°-29.38°)+\sin(90°-29.20°)\sin(90°-29.38°)\cos(81.02°-10.16°)$$

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why I was getting 4900 instead of 4201 when I tried to calculate the distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the Spherical Law of Cosines as it appears in UCSMP *Functions, Statistics, and Trigonometry*, 3rd ed., copied here because the diagram is good and helps with clarity.

[image: Spherical Law of Cosines (from UCSMP Functions, Statistics, and Trigonometry, 3rd ed.)]

If $\triangle ABC$ is a spherical triangle with arcs $a$, $b$, and $c$ (meaning the measures of the arcs, not the lengths), then $\cos c=\cos a\cos b+\sin a\sin b\cos C$.

Now, to the specific problem at hand.  Let's use the diagram below, also from UCSMP *Functions, Statistics, and Trigonometry*, 3rd ed., for reference.

[image: globe (from UCSMP Functions, Statistics, and Trigonometry, 3rd ed.)]

Let $A$ and $B$ be as you defined them.  $N$ and $S$ are the north and south poles, respectively; $C$ and $D$ are the points on the equator that are on the same line of longitude as $A$ and $B$, respectively.  Consider spherical $\triangle ABN$.  $a=(90°-\text{latitude of point }B)$; $b=(90°-\text{latitude of point }A)$. $N=\text{positive difference in longitude between points }A\text{ and }B$.  Use the Spherical Law of Cosines ($\cos n=\cdots$ form) to determine $n$, which is the shortest arc between the two points.

*(graphics from Lesson 5-10 of UCSMP Functions, Statistics, and Trigonometry, 3rd ed., © 2010 Wright Group/McGraw Hill)*